# Bug with duplicate display names and responses feed?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, notifications, display-names, feed

I just received a notification from stackoverflow that I had a new response to one of my questions.The question is this one:

[Play audio from a stream using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184683/play-audio-from-a-stream-using-c/5081173#5081173)

This questions is asked by someone called Martin, but that's not me, it's another Martin.

As far as I can see/remember I have never answered, commented on or even read this question. Why is it showing up in my new responses?

The users in question are:

[The other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25782/martin)
[Me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108234/martin)

Comment: You have the question marked as a favorite. Is that because of this incident, or has it been that way for a while? If it is the latter, then you got the notification because you probably are marked to get notifications for updates to favorites (and I'll promote this to an answer if that's the case).

Comment: *facepalm* I feel like an idiot now. It has been that way for a while, well spotted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a very curious point where the user display names happen to be the same, but this is caused by your subscription to the question as a favorite.

You probably have your profile setup to receive notifications to updates on favorites, in the "prefs" tab, which will make you receive such alerts as if it were your own question.